# Django ManyToManyField between 2 objects that point to one another

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

In my project, I have 2 models with a ManyToMany field that point to each other. In this case, I have Elections and Candidates. The idea is that an Election can have multiple Candidates and that a Candidate can also be part of multiple elections (One 'Candidate' is only one person).

I have the following:

project/elections/models.py

```
from candidates.models import Candidate

class Election(models.Model):
    candidates = models.ManyToManyField(Candidate)
    ...
```

project/candidates/models.py

```
from elections.models import Election
    elections = models.ManyToManyField(Election)
    ...
```

When I try to run any command (makemigrations, runserver, etc.) I get a circular dependency between Election and Candidate which crashes. I have the models in different apps as a coding practice.

> Should I:
>
> 1. Move both models to one app and one file
> 2. Not have the models pointing to each other (how would I  then accomplish my goal?)
> 3. Do something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do not need to do this**. A many-to-many field is already bidirectional. Just define it on *one* side, and use the reverse relation.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid circular dependency don't import the models, use strings instead, and include the applications name as namespace

project/elections/models.py

```
class Election(models.Model):
    candidates = models.ManyToManyField('candidates.Candidate')
```

**Update**

As the django docs points out, you only need to declare the relation on one of the models https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

> It doesn’t matter which model has the ManyToManyField, but you should
>   only put it in one of the models – not both.

Comment: Although this will solve OP's error, it is not the correct solution.